# How to add meta tags to facebook fan page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I am currently owning this page called

https://www.facebook.com/SocioTechnocrats

and the meta tag name describes something about facebook.

So how can i add few meta tags to it

Comment: I'am quite sure this is just not possible ...

Answer (score 0):

Not possible - log a request with Facebook.